# Getting time zone date command line linux

Tags: linux, date, timezone, utc

I'm trying to use `$date -u` to get UTC time zone. It works fine but how can i set GTM to get a different time zone. For example, how can i complete that command to check GMT+5 or GMT+6 time zone in command line in Linux?

Any idea how can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the timezone just for the one call to the `date` command (without changing the timezone that your system is set to) like so:

```
TZ=Asia/Calcutta date
```

Note the space before the `date` command.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the wrong way, but try setting the time zone, then calling date, then unsetting the time zone.

```
export TZ=Asia/Calcutta
date
unset TZ
```

There's a small list here of the time zones: [Link To Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).